Iterate over multiple dataframe and grouped them based on mean value
I have a list of dataframes with 81 different dataframes.
I would like to calculate the average value of the same column in each dataframes. Based on the mean values I would like to compare and grouped the dataframes. Average with values close to each other form a new, merged dataframe.
Example:
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['1','2','3','4','5'], 'Töltőtömeg':['70','69','71','70','70.5']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['1','2','3','4','5'], 'Töltőtömeg':['72','69','70','70','71.5']})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['1','2','3','4','5'], 'Töltőtömeg':['148','149','150','151','151']})
df4 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['1','2','3','4','5'], 'Töltőtömeg':['150','150','151','149','148']})

Expected output:
df12
0   1   70
1   2   69
2   3   71
3   4   70
4   5   70.5
5   1   72
6   2   69
7   3   70
8   4   70
9   5   71.5

df34
0   1   148
1   2   149
2   3   150
3   4   151
4   5   151
5   1   150
6   2   150
7   3   151
8   4   149
9   5   148


Don't create a new, otherwise exactly the same question, just because the previous one was closed. Instead, take note of the advice given there, [edit] that question accordingly, and ask for it to be considered for re-opening. At the moment, your question still lacks clarity: e.g., your expected dfs do not show any calculated values; also it is unclear what logic determines the grouping of df1 and df2 vs. df3 and df4, esp. considering a list with an odd number of dfs (81).

@ouroboros1 I agree there is room for improvement, but to also be fair there was some effort made and I can actually understand what OP wants now (clustering the dataframes by average, then concatenating).

@mozway Yes, the effort is nice, but ambiguity remains (though your interpetation seems plausible). One should not need an A to understand the actual Q... More importantly, the effort does not make it acceptable to open a new Q. At a minimum, OP should remove the old Q, to not clutter the site or waste the time of others visiting the old Q. This is the 2nd time, in fact: see dupl and orig—as you may recall ;).

@ouroboros1 I have to say I had not paid attention that they previously asked two similar questions. I agree, the old (now useless) questions should be removed. LehelTompos please pay attention in the future and try to be explicit from the beginning and with a valid [mre], this will save everyone's time!

IIUC, you want to group the dataframes by their proximity based on the average of a column, then concatenate them.
For this you could compute all means, sort them and identify the groups using a threshold (above which you consider them in a different group). Finally concat per group:
threshold = 10 # minimal distance between groups

dfs = [df2, df1, df3, df3]
avg = np.array([pd.to_numeric(d['Töltőtömeg']).mean() for d in dfs])
# [70.1, 70.5, 149.8, 149.8]

groups = pd.Series(avg).sort_values().diff().gt(threshold).cumsum()

out = [pd.concat([dfs[i] for i in v], ignore_index=True)
       for v in groups.index.groupby(groups).values()]

Output:
[  ID Töltőtömeg
 0  1         70
 1  2         69
 2  3         71
 3  4         70
 4  5       70.5
 5  1         72
 6  2         69
 7  3         70
 8  4         70
 9  5       71.5,
   ID Töltőtömeg
 0  1        148
 1  2        149
 2  3        150
 3  4        151
 4  5        151
 5  1        148
 6  2        149
 7  3        150
 8  4        151
 9  5        151]

Intermediate:
groups.index.groupby(groups)
# {0: [1, 0], 1: [2, 3]}

